# Clustering structured data in Deep learning

Tags: python, deep-learning, cluster-analysis, data-science

Are there any Deep Learning literature/references where they performed clustering in structured data?
I know it can be done using Kmeans, GMM etc. But is there any chance that cluster analysis to be done using Deep Neural Nets and the like? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Neural networks can be used in a clustering pipeline. For example, you can use [Self-organizing maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-organizing_map) (SOMs) for dimensionality reduction and k-means for clustering. Also, auto-encoders directly pop to my mind. But then, again, it is rather compression / dimensionality reduction than clustering. The real clustering is done by something else.

The problem with clustering is the missing optimization goal. The problem is not well-defined.

Answer (score 1):

Deep learning refers to the depth of the neural nets in and the huge number of parameters applied to learn how to recognize features related to a certain object, and neural nets in essence need a loss function to learn, and the loss should be in the form of an equation that can by applying calculus give an estimate of how much each parameter we need to correct to get better result (Basically forward propogation to predict and backward propogation to update parameters), and such a loss function as of now does not exist, so we don't use neural nets for clustering. And if no neural nets, no deep learning.

If any part of that seems confusing comment below.

To read more about clustering algorithm have a look at this https://towardsdatascience.com/the-5-clustering-algorithms-data-scientists-need-to-know-a36d136ef68

Again you will find no neural nets. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

If you do a little bit of literature *research* yourself you will find that people have repeatedly published clustering with deep neural networks.

Except that it doesn't seem to work anywhere but on MNIST data...

Answer (score 0):

Two other Potential Methods:

1. KMeans + Autoencoder (a simple deep learning architecture with
   kmeans and reducing the dimensionality of the data using autoencoders).
2. Deep Embedded Clustering algorithm (advanced deep learning)